# How should one generalize the proper radiation reaction force of a charge to any Lorentz frame?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, special-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, classical-electrodynamics

In section 8 of Medina's paper [Radiation reaction of a classical quasi-rigid
extended particle](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0508031), he writes

> The motion equations of the dressed mass, (56) and (57), show that the radiation reaction is a mass-conserving force. Then, the four-force of the radiation reaction of the physical point charge is in the rest frame
>   $$K^i_R = \frac{2q^2}{3c^3m}\frac{dF_{ex}^i}{dt},\quad K^0_R=0\tag{92}$$

$F_{ex}$ is the external force acting on the point charge and I'm OK with this bit. He immediately concludes:

> Therefore, if we call $K^\mu$ the external four-force and $\tau$ the proper time, the radiation reaction four-force is in an arbitrary reference frame given by 
>   $$K^i_R = \frac{2q^2}{3c^3m}(\frac{dK^\mu}{d\tau}+ (\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{dK^\nu}{d\tau}u_\nu)u^\mu)\tag{94}$$

The obvious way of generalizing (92) to any other frame is by
$$K^i_R = \frac{2q^2}{3c^3m}\frac{dK^\mu}{d\tau}$$

Why didn't he do it this way?

Comment: We know that $K^{\mu}u_{\mu}=0$ (that is, they must be perpendicular, which also means that the generalized force must depend on velocity). One simple way to satisfy this is  to add a term that depend on velocity (you can easily verify that the proposed modification satisfy the above requirement).

Comment: @HughMungus If $K^\mu$ is rest mass preserving, then so is $\frac{d}{d\tau}K^\mu$ and therefore $\frac{d}{d\tau}K^\mu u_\mu = 0$

Comment: I do not believe so, see Eq. (95), but I might be missing something.

Comment: @HughMungus I see you're right in him claiming that it doesn't equal zero, yet he states that $K^0_R=0$ in the rest frame. And somehow he's ended up with the scalar product of a force with an acceleration rather than with a velocity... this is very confusing for me!